# how to wait until user quit text editor to take data to a variable using python?

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

In my Python command line tool I have a flag that I used to launch a text editor, but I want the terminal to wait until user has finished and exits the application and then pass on the text entered to a variable to be used later. I am guessing this can be done using a subprocess like below, but I am getting an error.

#### Code

```
pr = subprocess.Popen(sublime, stdin=diff.stdout)
while pr:
    data = pr.stdout.read()
    print data
```

#### Error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'.

Comment: in the case above i get data passed to sublime from  `diff`, but I want to further append to data and pass it on to data variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SublimeText's command-line launcher has an optional flag (IIRC it's `-w`) that makes it wait until the user closes the window to return.

However, you should be aware that you can't simply read from the text editor's stdout. You need to provide it with a temporary file for the user to edit, and then read the data back from that temp file once the `subl` command exits.

Comment: even then I am not getting it to work
in that case I get this error:     `raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` and this is how I am launching sublime: `/Applications/Sublime_Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n -w`

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz: I see 4 separate issues: 1- `AttributeError`: you can't use `stdout.read()` unless you pass `stdout=PIPE` but it won't help with other issues in this case 2- *"No such file"* `OSError`: pass the command as a list (one list item per command-line argument) 3- how to wait for the editor  4- *"take data to a variable"* (3 and 4 issues are addressed in this answer).